# Show dynamic website on DIV or other element form, php, php function

Tags: php, html

I have a page `page1.html` with a form.
I `POST` and receive the values of the inputs on `page2.php`.

To explain the matter the inputs will send:
(Values are NOT always the same)

```
$title = "This is a Title";
$url = "www.this_is_url.com";
$message = "This is a message";
```

Then (`page2.php`):

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

So I take the values and with the function `myfunction()` create and print a new page (with all the tags of a website, from `<Doctype>` until `</html>`)

What I want is to **display** this "new page" (without creating a file) on a `div` or other element of the `page2.php`.

So here´s the code of `page2.php`

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{

function myfunction() {

$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><head><title>Title WEB</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />';
echo '<style> body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style></head><body>';
echo "<br />" . $title . "<br /><br />" . $url . "<br /><br />" . $message;
echo "</body></html>"

}

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><head><title>Title WEB</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />';
echo '</head><body>';
echo "<div>";

myfunction();

echo "</div>";
echo "</body></html>"
}   

?>
```

Comment: Try to declare your function outside the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be defined inside an "if" block. You can call it within an "if" block, but should not define.

Here's the working code.

```
function myfunction() {
$title = $_POST['title'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
echo "<br>" . $title . "<br >". $url . "<br />" . $message;
}

if(!empty($_POST['title']) && !empty($_POST['url']) && !empty($_POST['message']) )
{
    myfunction();
}
```

It's a good idea to use empty() with $_POST

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `isset()`

```
function myfunction() {
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><head><title>Title WEB</title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />';
  echo '<style> body { width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; } </style></head><body>';
  echo "<br />" . $title . "<br /><br />" . $url . "<br /><br />" . $message;
  echo "</body></html>";
}

if(isset($_POST['title'] && $_POST['url'] && $_POST['message'])) {
  myfunction();
}
```